# tokenize/untokenize python string code so that it is compatible with interactive-mode

Tags: python, tokenize, interactive-mode

I have python code like that has this kind of structure

```
def main:

    ''' comment '''
    if True:
        print "do"
    print "done
```

This code is not compatible with the interactive-mode (for example if I copy/paste it in an interactive session). For this it would need to be :

```
def main:
    ''' comment '''
    if True:
        print "do"

    print "done"
```

otherwise the interactive mode breaks on Indentation problems.

Do you know a simple way to transform the code with the generate_token / untokenize chain ? I am a bit lost in the NL / NEWLINE / INDENT / DEDENT semantics.

I found this [Script to remove Python comments/docstrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769332/script-to-remove-python-comments-docstrings) that removes comments/docstrings. It looks like a perfect fit for my problem but it cannot sort it out to have a clean output on complex code.

Comment: I think you can just remove all lines that are empty and not in a string.

Comment: no. removing empty lines would make it work for def main: / '''comment''' but it would not add a line after print "do"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best I could come up with (resolved my issue)

```
def _python_interactive_indent(self, code):
    prev_toktype = tokenize.INDENT
    first_line = None
    last_lineno = -1
    last_col = 0

    output = ''

    tokgen = tokenize.generate_tokens(StringIO.StringIO(code).readline)
    indent = 0
    hasNL = False
    prefixed = False
    for toktype, ttext, (slineno, scol), (elineno, ecol), ltext in tokgen:
        done = False
        if toktype == tokenize.INDENT:
            indent = indent + 1
        if toktype == tokenize.DEDENT:
            indent = indent - 1
        if slineno > last_lineno:
            last_col = 0
        if not done and toktype == tokenize.NL:
            hasNL = True
            done = True
        if not done and toktype == tokenize.COMMENT:
            done = True
        if not done and toktype == tokenize.STRING and prev_toktype == tokenize.INDENT:
            done = True
        if not done and hasNL and toktype != tokenize.DEDENT and toktype != tokenize.INDENT:
            hasNL = False
            output = output + ("    " * indent) + '\n'
            output += "    " * indent
            prefixed = True
        if not done:
            if not prefixed and scol > last_col:
                output += (" " * (scol - last_col))
            output += (ttext)
        prefixed = False
        prev_toktype = toktype
        last_col = ecol
        last_lineno = elineno
    return output
```