# automatically remove comments in python code

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code to remove commnents in python code.
using regex pattern, especially for multilines.
I try to test it on some string but not comments,
it seems failing on specific cases.

```
import re, sys

def removeComments(text):
    """ remove comments.
        text: blob of text with comments (can include newlines)
        returns: text with comments removed
    """
    pattern = r"""
                            ##  --------- COMMENT ---------
           #.*?$           ##  Start of # .... comment
         |                  ##
           '''              ##  Start of ''' ... ''' comment
           [^*]*\*+         ##  Non-* followed by 1-or-more *'s
           (                ##
             [^/*][^*]*\*+  ##
           )*               ##  0-or-more things which don't start with /
                            ##    but do end with '*'
           /                ##  End of /* ... */ comment
         |                  ##  -OR-  various things which aren't comments:
           (                ##
                            ##  ------ " ... " STRING ------
             "              ##  Start of " ... " string
             (              ##
               \\.          ##  Escaped char
             |              ##  -OR-
               [^"\\]       ##  Non "\ characters
             )*             ##
             "              ##  End of " ... " string
           |                ##  -OR-
                            ##
                            ##  ------ ' ... ' STRING ------
             '              ##  Start of ' ... ' string
             (              ##
               \\.          ##  Escaped char
             |              ##  -OR-
               [^'\\]       ##  Non '\ characters
             )*             ##
             '              ##  End of ' ... ' string
           |                ##  -OR-
                            ##
                            ##  ------ ANYTHING ELSE -------
             .              ##  Anything other char
             [^/"'\\]*      ##  Chars which doesn't start a comment, string
           )                ##    or escape
    """
    regex = re.compile(pattern, re.VERBOSE|re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
    noncomments = [m.group(2) for m in regex.finditer(text) if m.group(2)]

    return "".join(noncomments)



def commentRemover(text):
    def replacer(match):
        s = match.group(0)
        if s.startswith('/'):
            return " " # note: a space and not an empty string
        else:
            return s
    pattern = re.compile(
        r'//.*?$|/\*.*?\*/|\'(?:\\.|[^\\\'])*\'|"(?:\\.|[^\\"])*"',
        re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE
    )
    return re.sub(pattern, replacer, text)



filename = 'test.py'
with open(filename) as f:
    # uncmtFile = removeComments(f.read())
    uncmtFile = commentRemover(f.read())
    print uncmtFile
```

But; it fails to recognize string with comments:

```
createTableStatements = (
  '''create table a1 (
       c1 varchar(128) primary key,
       c2 varchar(128),
       c3 integer
     )''',

)
    variable5 = {"a": \
                      """This text is not a comment
 t"""}
```

Is there a way to catch those special cases in regex ?
Or is it better to parse with a state variable ?

Comment: Maybe look at adapting this to your use case? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769332/script-to-remove-python-comments-docstrings

Comment: Where are the comments in your example?

Comment: no comments,all are strings : those ones are hard to catch

Comment: Find this one : http://liftoff.github.io/pyminifier/

Comment: I don't know that regular expressions are going to be powerful enough to capture this. Most programming languages internally use stateful regex to tokenize code and strip comments, so you may end up having to more or less tokenize the input to get the exact behavior you want.

Comment: Don't do the regex.  How about generating source from AST.  AST does not include comments.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748029/how-to-get-source-corresponding-to-a-python-ast-node