# How can I remove all comments from a Python script?

Tags: python

I get a file from the desktop that has a code of python like:

```
line 1 :#hi
line 2 :x=0
line 3 :#print x
line 4 :print "#" 
line 5 :print ' # the x is" , x 
line 6 :print "#"#
```

and I want to print in the programme :

```
line 1 :x=0
line 2 :print "#"
line 3 :print ' # the x is" , x
line 4 :print "#"
```

and I run in it my programme with fopen and I get any line apart, I want to print the lines but without the #...the # must be checked if is in "" or '' and if it is when we must print the line with the #.

I have open a file and get the lines apart and checked if the # is in the line when removing it but I can't find who to check if the # is in "" or '' and if it is then print all the line.

```
def remove_comments(line,sep="#"):
    for s in sep:
        i = line.find(s)#find the posision of  #
        if i >= 0 :
            line = line[:i]#the line is until the # - 1
    return line.strip()

f=open("C:\Users\evogi\OneDrive\Desktop\ergasia3 pats\kodikaspy.txt","r")
for line in f :
    print remove_comments(line)
```

and the result is :

```
line 1 :
line 2 :x=0
line 3 :
line 4 :print "
line 5 :print '
line 6 :print "
```

Comment: You are mixing up " and '

Comment: You need a proper parser to do this correctly. Look at the module `ast`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Script to remove Python comments/docstrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769332/script-to-remove-python-comments-docstrings)

Answer (score 3):

The function `string.find()` *returns the index of first occurence of the substring*. So in your case you want to look for lines where it returns `0` (then the `#` is the first character, i.e. a comment).

So you could do something like

```
def remove_comments(line,sep="#"):
    for s in sep:
        i = line.find(s)#find the posision of  #
        if i == 0 :
            line = None
    return line.strip()

f=open("C:\Users\evogi\OneDrive\Desktop\ergasia3 pats\kodikaspy.txt","r")
for line in f :
    if remove_comments(line):
        print remove_comments(line)
```